# How to run SPECfp benchmarks on verilog module?

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, floating-point, verilog

I have created a verilog FPU and I was wondering how I would go about running SPECfp benchmarks on it, or is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coordination  between e.g. memory access and floating point arithmetic is critical to real-world floating point performance, which is what SPECfp is intended to measure. Often, the limiting factor is getting the operands to the floating point ALU, and the results back to memory, not doing the arithmetic once the right operands are in the right registers.

Do you have a model of the whole processor and memory? If so, how fast does it run? Processor designers do run benchmarks on models, but it takes a lot of compute power.

Comment: I don't have an entire model. Is this same statement that you made true regarding getting SoftFloat to run?

Comment: I don't know, because I don't know anything about SoftFloat. Your best starting point would be a very simple benchmark that is dominated by a small core. You could then write a Verilog model of the rest of the behavior for that specific benchmark. Maybe a Linpack?

Answer (score 3):

The SPEC benchmarks are software (I believe SPECfp is entirely in C and Fortran, but I'm not sure).  You don't run them on arbitrary hardware components, you run them on a complete system with a compiler and runtime environment.  If all you have is an FPU, you'll need to mate it with something that can run general code, and then come up with a compiler back end to target your custom architecture.